# pandas: writing the first row of a dataframe by vertical order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
   A B C
0 'a' 1 2
1 'b' 3 4
```

I want to write just a first line of the data frame to a text file with the dtype of each column, so the result will be:

`A str 'a'
B int 1
C int 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
q=df.dtypes.reset_index(name='dtype')
p=df.loc[0].reset_index(name='row')
newdf=pd.merge(q,p,on='index')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df1 = df.iloc[[0]].dtypes.replace({'object':'str'}).to_frame().join(df.iloc[0].rename('a'))

df1.to_csv(file, header=None, sep='\s')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for col in df.columns:
        f.write(' '.join((col, str(df[col].dtype), str(df.loc[0, col]))))
        f.write('\n')
```